# TypeError: cannot read property of undefined - angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

It's supposed to display the categories list data from the database of the backend into a table in the frontend. but, no data has been displayed yet, because of this error.

**categories-list.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoriesService, Category } from '@bluebits/products';

@Component({
  selector: 'admin-categories-list',
  templateUrl: './categories-list.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class CategoriesListComponent implements OnInit {

  categories: Category[] = []

  constructor(private categoriesService: CategoriesService) { }

  private getCategories() {
    this.categoriesService.getCategories().subscribe( (data:any) => {
      this.categories = data.categories
      console.log(data)
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCategories()
  }
}
```

**categories.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Category } from '../models/category';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CategoriesService {

  apiMainUrl= "http://localhost:3000/api/v1"

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.http.get<Category[]>(`${this.apiMainUrl}/categories`)
  }
}
```

**categories-list.html**

```
 <ng-template pTemplate="body" *ngFor="let category of categories" let-category>
        <tr>
            <td>{{category.id}}</td>
            <td>{{category.name}}</td>
            <td>{{category.icon}}</td>
        </tr>
 </ng-template>
```

Comment: Can you give the exact line at which the error appears?

Comment: try `data.body.categories`

Comment: @Nicho it didn't work :\

Comment: @EslamGohar can you also show result of `console.log(data)` as a sample

Comment: @Nicho Normally, it returns an object of data in the console like that {success: true, data: Array(7)}, but can't show this data in the table!

Comment: @mikegross I can't determine where the error is, but I think it comes from the getCategories function in "categories-list.component.ts".

Comment: @EslamGohar you should have a log in your console with the exact line of this error. Please copy paste it and indicate at which line it's failing... Your error largely has to do with trying to read a property of an undefined object, which for example here would be `category`. It would help a lot to know where the error comes from...

Comment: Try to make console.log(data.data)

Comment: @RebaiAhmed I have done what you said but it returns "Array(7)" in the console without displaying this data on the table!!

Comment: Try then to inject this.categories = data.data

Comment: @RebaiAhmed Thanks bro ♥ though I have tried more and it wasn't being worked. but, Finally, It's worked now :D

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your using PrimeNG for your table. I don't think you use ngFor on the ng-template element. I think you need to remove ngFor and cahnge the iterator should be `let-categories` this in the template you can't access each item with categories.id.

Comment: I have removed ngFor and changed the iterator as you said. but, I couldn't get the correct result which displays the categories data on the table

Comment: Are you getting back? like the console.log? If so try piping the 'categories' into the template

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved this issue. It was in the `getCategories()` function, which should be call:

````
this.categories = data.data```
````

NOT

```
this.categories = data.categories
```

So that the array of data can be displayed on a table in the frontend.